# Concurrent Session Control in Shiro

Tags: spring-boot, shiro

I want to limit the number of concurrent sessions to 1 per user.  If the user logs in from a 2nd client/IP, I'd like to invalidate his previous session (if there is one) and create a new session for the current client. So the user should be denied access and redirected if he makes another request from the 1st client.

I'm using Shiro in my Spring boot application. It's a pure API server, not a web app. Front end and backend are separated.

It seems that Shiro doesn't not have session limit support out of the box.

I'm wondering where I should perform the operations?

Currently I have my own

```java
public class AuthRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
        // Get user from db and return authentication info
    }

}
```

I wonder if it's a clean place to add the corresponding logics? Or should I the previous session after login and the 2nd client's session has been created?

I think it might make more sense to do it in

```java
public class AuthRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    @Override
    protected void assertCredentialsMatch(AuthenticationToken token, AuthenticationInfo info) throws AuthenticationException {
        // Credentials verified

        // Invalidate previous session
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        Session existingSession = subject.getSession(false);
        if (existingSession != null) {
                SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager().logout(subject);
                existingSession.stop();
        }       
    }
}
```

But it turns out Shiro creats a new subject, with a new session tied to it, per login, not per user.  So the `subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject()` will always be a brand-new one and it's impossilbe to retrieve the same user and then retrieve its session. Any idea?

Comment: is your API server stateless or is the client expected to hold a token/cookie?  If it is stateless and you want to limit the client to a single request you find it challenging with how some HTTP clients work see: https://medium.com/inloopx/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace

Also, if you have caching enabled your `doGetAuthenticationInfo` method would not get called, so you would need to implement something higher up. Your best bet would probably be some sort of Filter. But you also run the increased risk of invalidating a session mid request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, I found the best way is to write a custom `SecurityManager`:

```java
    public class UniquePrincipalSecurityManager extends DefaultWebSecurityManager {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthRealm.class);


        @Override
        public Subject login(Subject subject, AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
            AuthenticationInfo info;

            // Verify credentials
            try {
                info = authenticate(token);
            } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
                try {
                    onFailedLogin(token, ae, subject);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                        logger.info("onFailedLogin method threw an " +
                                "exception.  Logging and propagating original AuthenticationException.", e);
                    }
                }
                throw ae; //propagate
            }

            // Check the subject's existing session and stop it if present
            DefaultWebSessionManager sm =  (DefaultWebSessionManager) getSessionManager();
            User loggedInUser = (User)(info.getPrincipals().getPrimaryPrincipal());

            for (Session session : sm.getSessionDAO().getActiveSessions()) {
                SimplePrincipalCollection p = (SimplePrincipalCollection) session.getAttribute(DefaultSubjectContext.PRINCIPALS_SESSION_KEY);

                User sessionUser = null;
                if (p != null) {
                    sessionUser = (User)(p.getPrimaryPrincipal());
                }
                if (sessionUser != null && loggedInUser.getId().equals(sessionUser.getId())) {
                    session.stop();
                    sm.getSessionDAO().delete(session);
                }
            }

            // Create new session for current login
            Subject loggedIn = createSubject(token, info, subject);
            onSuccessfulLogin(token, info, loggedIn);

            return loggedIn;
        }
    }
```

Note that only delete the previous session after you've verified the credentials.

With this approach, you have to write your own session manager and sessionDAO as well if you want to store your session in another data store.

Note that I used Spring Session with redis before, but with this custom security manager, it no longer works since session management won't be delegated to `HttpSession` anymore.

Comment: Could you show the shiro.ini configuration? or if you set your custom 'SecurityManager' programatically, how you do it? I'm trying something like you did here in my application, but the session does not stay authenticated in the subsequent acess after the login (the login runs fine, but in the next access, subject.isAuthenticated() returns false, and getSessionDAO().getActiveSessions() is always empty). 
My guess is I'm missing something in the shiro.ini configuration, but I can't figure out what is

Comment: every login to the system fetch every active sessions to memory is not scalable. likely shiro should implement some lookup function rather than downstream loop through every session to search.